# Cannot find class [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration] for bean with name

Tags: spring, ignite, gridgain

I am trying to integrate Apache Ignite into my another spring boot java application and here is my pom.xml  dependencies looks like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-rest-http</artifactId>
    <version>${apache.ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring-data_2.0</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-ml</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-ml-xgboost-model-parser</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-ml-spark-model-parser</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.gridgain</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-ml-tensorflow-model-parser</artifactId>
    <version>${gridgain.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In my desperation, I have included all the dependencies included in gridgain samples project.
Here is my very simple code where I am trying to create a cache:

```
try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("config/dev.config.client.xml")) 
{       
    ignite.configuration().setClientMode(true);
    //I have ccfg defined in code where I create a cache configuration
    ignite.addCacheConfiguration(ccfg);

    try (IgniteCache<String, CacheResponse> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(ccfg)) 
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Should have created a cache now");
    }
}
```

Here is my ignite configuration file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">   
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>              
                                <value>HOST1:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>HOST2:47500..47509</value>
                                <value>HOST3:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>     
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I run my application, I get the following exception:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class [org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration] for
>   bean with name 'org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration#0'
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Work/Java/gravitee.io/1.30.1/graviteeio-gateway-1.30.1/config/dev.config.client.xml];
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration

Comment: Have you added GridGain repository? Also, what version do you use(gridgain.version)?

Comment: Yes, I added the gridgain repository. I can "mvn install" my application fine. I use 8.7.12 gridgain. By the way, I am just trying to  develop a plugin for gravitee.io

Comment: Can you share a reproducer project on Github so that we could check?

Comment: It seems to be a classpath-related issue, how do you run your code? By the way I've noticed that `uhcsr.dev.config.client.xml` differs from `dev.config.client.xml`.

Comment: alamar, I can share a plugin on github but that requires the whole setup of gravitee.io since I am developing a plugin for the gravitee.io. Is it perfectly fine? I can do that if you want me to.

Comment: Vladimir, I am running it as a plugin for gravitee.io. Do you want me to post the complete pom.xml so that you can see the complete dependency? And sorry for changing the XML file names. Message is from the old file.. the current XML configuration file is dev.config.client.xml and it looks exactly the same as I posted above.